# Enable key repeat in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, appkit

I think it started in Mac OS Lion: when pressing and holding a key, a pop-up window with accented characters shows up, instead of repeating the key.

This can be disabled by setting the `ApplePressAndHoldEnable` preference but this is not what I'm after.

Is it possible to disable the pop up, i.e. to enable key repeating, in `NSTextView` instance programmatically?

Comment: It started in Lion. Tiger was long before iOS where it was borrowed from.

Comment: What happens if you override https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/completionsForPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:

Comment: @uchuugaka: thanks, corrected. I guess "word completions" are a bit different...

Comment: What happens if you override completionsForPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:

Comment: @uchuugaka: nothing wrt to key repeat, i.e. still pops up that character map.

Comment: Hmm. Did you return nil? if not the that, then you might try one of the spellchecker methods. Otherwise it could be in another class or it isn't avail